# Survival analysis of inadequate data

Tags: survival

I'm trying to analyze U.S soldiers survival rate of Korean War

in data, there is a column about dates when they passed away during War

but there is no data(column) about dates when they were deployed to Korea (the time when they were exposed to the possibility of death)

so, I can't know the exact time how long U.S Soldiers were alive during War

I thought that Left censoring could be an answer to solve this problem

but I'm not sure I can use Left censoring even though I can't know

the exact period how long soldiers survived.

I want to know If I can use survival analysis in this case

I searched the Internet for a week, but in the end, I haven't found the

way to solve this problem.

If someone gives comments about this to me, it will be greatly helpful.

Thank you

Comment: Do you have any additional information? E.g. with the information on how many did not die and a standard length (is that how it worked?) of a tour of duty Korea, you could use left-censoring. You may need to make parametric assumptions. You might also bee able to use other information like start of military service for each plus some assumptions or information from other wars in that era.

Comment: the data is about whole soldiers who had engaged in Korean War and passed away during War. so there is no one who is survived. I can know when they were born(age), but can't know when they start to belong to Army.

Comment: Not knowing about survivors will be a major issue, I doubt you can do much with this data alone. You may want to ask for additional data.  Depending on the system for conscription (during the Vietnam war it was a birthday based lottery, no idea whether that was used during Korean war, too) and length of duty tours the birthday may still tell you a lot.

Comment: Thank you for good comment. data is about soldiers who died away during war, so soldiers who didn't die during War is not included in data.